# Returning an echo using session control

Tags: php

I am working with sessions in PHP. The user enters in his name and password and this is then posted to a php page which starts a session if the credentials exist in the database table which then allows the user to view certain pages if valid, or return to login if invalid. 
Everything with the database and session works, except when the user is not logged in it is supposed to echo "You are not logged in". and return to the login page. It returns to the login page just fine, but I am not seeing the message anywhere. Can anyone tell me if the order of the code is incorrect, or another method to display the error without having a page just to display the error?

```
    <?php
session_start();

echo '<h1>Employees Only</h1>';

if (isset($_SESSION['valid_user']))
{
    if ($_SESSION['valid_user'])
    {
        echo "<p>You are currently logged in as " . $_SESSION['valid_user'] . "</p>";

        $form  = "<form action=\"logout.php\" method=\"post\">";
        $form .= "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"logout\" value=\"Log Out\">";
        $form .= "</form>";
        echo $form;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<p>You are not logged in.</p>";
        header("Location:login1.html");
        exit();
    }
}
else
{
    echo "<p>You are not logged in.</p>";
    header("Location:login1.html");
    exit();
}
    ?>
```

The echo "You are not logged in". will not display, but it is returning to login1.html

Comment: How do you expect it to both display the message and redirect?

Comment: What does $_SESSION['valid_user'] contains?

Comment: @chandresh_cool That is of no importance. The problem is redirection of the page

Comment: @asprin If the condition is satisfied, he won't be redirected

Comment: it is important please check again

Comment: True, So is there another method to display the error, perhaps at the top of the page it redirects to. But only if it is redirected.

Comment: you can pass that message in url or you can store in session and then display where you want

Comment: Theres no use in having an echo just before you send a header telling the browser to redirect.

Comment: My bad...didn't read it properly

Comment: $_SESSION['valid_user'] = $userName;   from the previous page

Comment: Just be aware from the php docs http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php - `Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.`

Answer (score 0):

Use this, it will wait for 5 seconds and after that it will redirected to `login1.html`.

```
header( 'refresh: 5; url=login1.html' );
echo '<h1>You will be re-directed in 5 seconds...</h1>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I reckon it's because you're using `header('location:login1.html')`. It redirects the client immediately.
Try using `header( 'Refresh:2; url=login1.html' );`. It will wait for `x` seconds *(2 in this case)*, and then redirect. You can read more about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can't redirect the user and at the same time expect he has time to see the message you are sending. You need to take a step back and divide the process, save it into a variable and show it to the user on the next page for instance.

There are various ways of accomplishing that, the most popular though, used by most web frameworks is making a "flash message" that will only exist in the session until the next page reload, thus displaying only once to the user.

This [article](http://baylorrae.com/add-flash-messages-to-your-site/) shows you how to do it. There are a bunch more on google if you wish to use something existing.